Is there a Linux memory API to insert a block in my address space?

Suppose I have a data structure, and wish a component to grow. There are two choices. Either I create a linked structure and connect  new chunks of memory with pointers, or I can allocate a single block of memory, and grow when needed.
However, the MMU can map blocks into memory. Is there a way to allocate blocks of memory into specific places in memory?
What I am looking for is schematically like this:
constexpr int PAGE = 64*1024*1024;
char* p1 = aligned_alloc(32, PAGE);
char* p2 = aligned_alloc(32, PAGE);
char* temp = allocate_page_at(p1 + PAGE, PAGE);

I realize that in implementing something like this, freeing the memory using the existing set of routines would no longer work, because the pointers would be different. So I'm not claiming that this is doable using malloc, aligned_alloc, it would presumably be lower level, involving writing an API to allocate blocks of memory.
One way I can think of implementing this would be to reserve large blocks of address space, and control how much of them gets filled. Something like:
char* p = allocate(size, maxsize);

that would give the ability to grow without having to manage all the pointers.
Does Linux have primitives to make this happen?

mmap() allows you to specify the address that the new memory should be mapped to. But you can't map to arbitrary addresses, since it may already be in use, and mappings have to be on page boundaries.

Why not just use malloc() and realloc(). realloc() will simply extend the allocation if possible.

@Barmar because realloc will copy all the memory. I am trying to avoid copying, just moving data by remapping memory.

It will only copy it if necessary. Often malloc() leaves extra space so it can grow without copying. Although if you're growing by a large amount, there usually won't be that much elbow room.

Allocating the max is probably the best solution. Because of overcommit, the excess allocation has little cost if you never use it.
